# Whats missing in calculation of Physical Memory?

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have calculation table of processes who are taking piece of Total Physical memory, here it is:

How I see, total memory of these list is about 400 mb, but at the same time on next tab it shows total used memory 2gb+.

Why?

Screenshots:
  [image: processes]
[image: tab]

Comment: Click the delete button next to the edit to delete your own question

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Instead of deleting your question, consider providing your solution as an answer so that others can benefit. That is the reason this site exists.

Comment: Did you try to check if it's a better fit you click "show all processes"? On the lower left you can also see that you currently have 69 processes running and your current list has around 20-30 listed. So there is a rather big chunk missing. This includes system processes or processes of other users - depending on how you use your machine.

Answer (score 0):

The task manager rounds up or rounds down the memory usage values per process.

All we see is that processes are taking up the memory, not only these processes, but also integrated video card memory, the cache, the kernel, other users' processes(such as the system) are taking up the memory. There are probably a lot of other things that take up memory, but very little.

[image]

And some process can also be hidden (negative PID, running as another user).

[image]

It takes about 2G of memory to run Windows 7 without running other programs.

So I think what you see should be normal.